# Whenever I hold alt/option and move my mouse, Mac OS X resizes my window... how do I stop that?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using Mac OS X for maybe 6 years now, and I have no idea what's causing this. Maybe someone else has this experience and can help me out.

Symptom: while holding the alt/option key, if I move my mouse the current window starts resizing, anchored at the top left (it behaves exactly as if I had clicked-and-dragged the lower-right icon on the window).

Anyone have an idea of what I may have installed that caused this? Or how to make it stop?

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out, the culprit was the latest release of [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate that in the BetterTouchTool preferences. (Window Moving & Resizing)